# WCF Web Service Windows Form Interaction

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, wcf, client-server

What I would like to achieve is to have a Windows Form Application as my host application, which does following:

When the user makes a request to the service, the user is supplied with some data from the service and at the same time a response is sent from the server to my host application(for example change label text to "done").

```
Client -> Service -> "Host"
```

I have tried creating a WCF service library, then referencing to my form application and then

```
 Form1 frm = new Form1();
 frm.Label1Text = "Done";
```

`Label1Text` is a property of `label1`.

By now I had no success.

P.S. I am also open for suggestions for such a scenario.

Comment: You're trying to use a Windows Form as a WCF service host?  Who's the client in this case?  You'll need to host the service library somehow, you can't just reference it like a normal class library.

Comment: I do debug, and it's getting hosted, probably local IIS or whatever(not really sure, because im new to VS).